# Double quotes not printing properly | Firefox | Lato Fonts|

Tags: html, css, firefox

While creating a webpage I notice that double quotes are being produced erroneously in firefox (54.0 for Ubuntu) as shown in the picture: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0kI9.png)

This is supposed to be: information," in Proc. .

This looks alright in chrome.

I used the following font in my html code:

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body {
margin:0;
font-size: 100%;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: There is no problem in this code. Only thing i can think of is your keyboard input is different than English, I tested and got the correct quotes. Check your system keyboard input if you are using other than English as input

Comment: @ShanilFernando — If the problem was the keyboard input then the problem would show up when the character was typed, not when it was loaded in a browser.

Comment: @Quentin Yes I agree. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html4 you could try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

HTML5

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

You should close style tag:

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" 
rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    body {
        margin:0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Dont forget html tags.

I hope this help you.

Comment: ISO-8859-1? What century is this? UTF-8 should be the default now.